# Estimating impact of indexes SQLite database size

Tags: index, sqlite, size

I'm trying to estimate the database size (on disk) for a SQLite DB that includes a number of indexed columns. These columns are of (SQLite) type Integer and String. It's straightforward enough to estimate the size per row with these columns, but I'm not sure how to account for the extra per-row padding due to the indexes. What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least some of the [details of index B-trees are documented](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#index_btrees).

It might be easier to just create a test database, populate it, and measure the file size before and after creating an index.

Comment: I did end up creating a test database as you suggested. Of course the results would be specific to my schema, but in case its helpful to anyone I measured a 9% decrease in size when I dropped the indexes (which I rounded to 10% for estimation purposes).